# GUI Elements Not Showing Immediately

Tags: java, swing

I made a redesign to my gui in java and it is facing an issue, the icons don't show until i grab the gui and shake it, sometimes they show half then i have to grab it by the mouse and check it again for the icons to show, what could be causing that and how to fix it ?

Comment: update : when i grab the gui and drag it outside of the screen then back in the icons appear

Comment: the items that are not showing are located inside another item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible
2. If you add components to a panel on a visible frame, then you need to invoke `revalidate()` on the panel after adding all the components.